# Remove or delete a review from my iTunes app?

Tags: applications, app-store-connect

How can I remove a customer review from my App in iTunes?

I sent a message via **Report a Concern** and nothing happened.

Comment: @psycho OP has mentioned that they have already done this, and actually posted this question as an answer on that question which was subsequently deleted.

Comment: @grgarside Yep, but the answer's still the same : as stated in your first answer, it's not possible and reporting a concern is the only way to attempt smthg. A comment under your answer or a new question specifically about reporting's expectations would be a better fit, to my mind. Currently, any visitor searching for "delete review" would read two threads without one adding any new information to the other.

Comment: Let's keep these together on the first thread. Ron you can edit in more information and this will get reviewed for re opening, but perhaps you should ask when to use report a concern versus contacting developer support directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting a concern is the only way to attempt to remove a review. The process is not instant and requires manual approval. If you've only just sent the form, wait a bit. If it's been a while and the review is still there, it probably means that someone has reviewed your complaint and declined it.

Comment: Do you have firsthand knowledge that this is true? What if Apple doesn't have enough people to look at every single incident?.Perhaps during busy weeks only the top 1000 posts that have accumulated the most flags get a human look.

Comment: @bmike Indeed, I agree that they probably won't get through them all, but I think they'll get through many of them, giving good chance that they'll go through your complaint.